# Oracle Import (IMPDP) Error with ORA-39068 ORA-39002 ORA-00942

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, impdp

while importing oracle12c data base getting below error...

```
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39068: invalid master table data in row with PROCESS_ORDER=-1
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

if I use different user then below error shows...

```
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39068: invalid master table data in row with PROCESS_ORDER=-1
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a couple of issues here. The `ORA-39002` and `ORA-39068` errors are typically caused by trying to run the import with invalid options. This often happens when the export is created by using a clause like `expdp ... EXCLUDE=REF_CONSTRAINT`, and then trying to run the import including that option `impdp ... INCLUDE=REF_CONSTRAINT`. To get around those errors, check to see what options were used during the export and make sure you are not trying to include invalid options during the import. Please see Oracle Support document 2176403.1 for more info (Data Pump Import Fails With ORA-39002  ORA-39068 ORA-00904 Errors): https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2176403.1

The `ORA-00942` error from the first set of messages is likely due the user not having the necessary permissions. If that user has not been assigned the `DBA` role or has not been explicitly granted the datapump-related privileges, they will not be able to run the import.

The `ORA-01422` error from the second set of messages looks to be hinting towards your database not being properly configured. Check to see if there are duplicate `DUAL` tables, and if so, drop the duplicate and you should be able to proceed with the import. Please view Oracle Support document 556649.1 for more info (Full DataPump Export Fails With Error ORA-1422) can be found at: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=556649.1

Hope this helps.